# Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wiring up a CMS (Craft) to a site built by another developer, and sorting through the problems that entails. Right now the big one is that i'm getting a "body is not defined" js error every time the page resizes. Specifically:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined
    at init.js:54
    at dispatch (jquery-2.0.0.min.js:4)
    at y.handle (jquery-2.0.0.min.js:4)
```

Example at: http://pollinator.creativeforthepeople.org

I'm loading the libraries in the right order, and I tried loading jquery from google, which also didn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Clay

Comment: Provide the code the error points to here so that we can look at it, but I suspect you meant to get the body dom object which is accessed by document.body and not just body

Comment: It should be `$('body')` not `$(body)`. Also, next time you post any question, post the related code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this screenshot from your site. http://prntscr.com/ewxc4i

You need to change this code in init.js on line 54 from:

```
if($(body).hasClass(no-touch) & $(window).width() > 992) {
```

to:

```
if($('body').hasClass(no-touch) & $(window).width() > 992) {
```

You need to set keyword **body** inside quotes.

Answer (score 3):

To js just `body` looks like a variable name. So it doesn't find where this variable has been declared.

So try

```
$('body')
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('body')` or `$(document.body)`

Besides, note that your scripts are included after the closing `</html>` tag

```
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<a id="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a>
<script src="P2/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Jquery Library Call -->
<script src="P2/vendor/prettyphoto/js/prettyphoto.js"></script> <!-- PrettyPhoto Plugin -->
<script src="P2/js/helper-plugins.js"></script> <!-- Helper Plugins -->
<script src="P2/js/bootstrap.js"></script> <!-- UI -->
<script src="js/custom-js.js"></script>
<script src="P2/js/init.js"></script> <!-- All Scripts -->
...
```

you should move them inside `body`